# Waiting for User input before continuing to Marionette Application next stage

Tags: backbone.js, marionette

My application needs a function to be called at initialize:after stage. After user has provided that input in function, i want application to go in start stage. But currently, it just go to all the 3 stages without waiting for input. Can anyone suggest how can i do acheive my desired functionality?

```
var app= new Marionette.Application();

    app.on('initialize:before', function(options){
        //do Something
    });

    app.on('initialize:after', function(options){
        //do Something
                //wait for User to give input before continuing to start stage.
    });

    app.on('start', function(options){
        //start only when User provide input.
                //do Something with input.
    });

    var options = {};

    app.start(options);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is less a Backbone/Marionette question and more of a pure JavaScript problem. If you don't care about usability, just use [window.prompt](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_prompt.asp) and save yourself a lot of work.

If you're not able to use `alert`s, then things get more complicated. User inputs are usually done using some sort of form. Unfortunately, these are asynchronous operations, meaning you can't just halt JavaScript execution while you wait for the user to get out their glasses and look for their SSN. [jQuery's Deferred library](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.Deferred/) is a good tool to use to handle situations like these, but you'll need to rework your code a little.

In our project we've created a the concept of a `Lifecycle` that works roughly as follows:

```
Module.lifecycle = {
    step1: function() {
        var dfd = new $.Deferred().resolve();
        // get user input from a custom dialog control
        var dialog = new MyDailogControl("What do you want to do?");
        dialog.onSuccess = dfd.resolve;
        dialog.onFail = dfd.reject;
        dialog.show();
        return dfd.promise();
    },
    step2: function() { /* load some data from the server */ },
    step3: function() { /* get even more user input... */ },
};
```

Next we have a Lifecycle Walker object that pushes the lifecycle through each state; it looks something like this (from memory; you'll want to test this...)

```
var Walker = function(lifecycle) {
    this.lifecycle = lifecycle;
    this._states = _.keys(this.lifecycle);
}

_.extend(Walker.prototype, Backbone.Events, {
    start: function() {
        this._index = 0;
        this.moveNext();
    },
    moveNext: function() {
        var step = this.states[this._index];

        this.trigger('before:' + step);

        $.when(this.lifecycle[step]())
            .then(function() {
                this.trigger('after:' + step);
                this._index++;
                if (this._active < this._states.length) {
                    this.moveNext();
                }
            });
    }
});
```

Tying the two ideas together, you'll do something like:

```
var walker = new Walker(MyModule.lifecycle);
walker.on('before:step1', function() { /* do something amazing */ });
walker.on('before:step2', function() { /* do something fantastic */ });
walker.on('after:step3', function() { /* do whatever */ });

walker.start();
```

So, we've basically implemented a bastardized Command Pattern using deferreds to solve problems like this. We hook into `module.start`, but there's no reason you couldn't do something similar on `app.start` instead.